# How to log the queries executed by Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to find the query that was run against the database in spring data mongodb?

I know this is possible in case of JPA. So was just wondering if there was something similar in Spring data MongoDB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show query while using query annotations with MongoRepository with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118047/how-to-show-query-while-using-query-annotations-with-mongorepository-with-spring)

Comment: Check out this Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217351/log-mongodb-queries-with-spring-boot/41789435#41789435

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the log level to `DEBUG` for `org.springframework.data.mongodb`.

Comment: I tried executing repository.findAll(predicate, sort) but the log only shows the filters but not the sort. Is there anyway I can see the sort query?

Comment: @user1955934 Yeah, also found this, in MongoTemplate class only find queries do not log sort part for unknown reasons

Answer (score 6):

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

To clarify Oliver's answer add that to the application.yml file or properties file.

Comment: Thanks! logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG worked for me in application.properties