# View the query that has been executed in mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

How can I view what query being created whiling executing the mongo query from spring boot application?

For example -

```
this.mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
```

After running this command what query is being created in MongoDB. How can I view that? Did some research and found **db.currentOp()** but this doesn't show any query.

I have set the profiling level to 2 `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

Comment: Why dont u log in the console

Comment: What do you mean log in the console ?

Comment: `logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.com.videoappservice.serviceImpl=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n`

Comment: you will see all the execution in terminal.  replace `com.videoappservice.serviceImpl` with your package which needs to be tracked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log the queries executed by Spring Data MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143140/how-to-log-the-queries-executed-by-spring-data-mongodb)

Comment: @Marc Yep it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for. Logging in terminal, add this into application.properties.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

These properties help you some more additional logging

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.com.videoappservice.serviceImpl=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n
```

`com.videoappservice.serviceImpl` with your package which needs to be tracked